# Is it possible to point multiple domains to single CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have multi tenant web app, I serve the correct version of the app based on the domain that made the request, on my app's domain it works perfectly using different subdomain for each app version, so users can go to `some-version.example.com` and see one version of the app, and then go to `another-version.example.com` and see another version of the app, each user has their own version in the user's desired subdomain on my app's root domain, now I want to be able to allow my users to point their custom domains (from wherever they purchased their domain from) to the app, so instead of going to `some-version.example.com` and see their app they'll be able to go to `domain-of-user.com` and see their app.

My app is behind CloudFront, so my problem is that I now have to add the domain to a new ACM certificate and then use the new certificate in CloudFront and also add the domain to CloudFront alternative domains, but all this causes invalidation of the old certificate meaning I'll have to revalidate all the domains again this time with the newly created certificate, and that's not an option for me.

My end goals is to be able to do this:

- `example.com` (my app's domain) -> CNAME points to -> `foo-bar.cloudfront.net`
- `client-domain.com` (my client's domain) -> CNAME points to -> `example.com` (or even directly to CF)
- I can now add more clients' domains without having to either create a certificate for them at all or without having to create a new certificate for the already issued ones.

Is this flow possible with CloudFront or possible with any other AWS service that can come in front of CloudFront and allow such behavior?

Answer (score 1):

> My app is behind CloudFront, so my problem is that I now have to add the domain to a new ACM certificate and then use the new certificate in CloudFront and also add the domain to CloudFront alternative domains, but all this causes invalidation of the old certificate meaning I'll have to revalidate all the domains again this time with the newly created certificate, and that's not an option for me.

That's how SSL works. It can't be avoided.

It sounds like in your case what you will need to do is create a new CloudFront distribution for each tenant/domain.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a solution I can handle at the moment, is it possible to open up CloudFront to allow any domain to CNAME it and serve it? (unapproved domains would be served an error page by my web app anyways so I'm not worried about that)

Comment: No, it will only serve the domains you have listed in the alternate domains configuration. Not to mention the web browser wouldn't let the page load because the domain wouldn't be in the CloudFront distribution's SSL certificate.